# What is the fd/2 equivalent on Windows?

Tags: windows, awk, stderr

On eg Linux one can refer to stderr as fd/2 from within an awk script. 
Example:
`if(system("test -e " myfile) != 0) myfile = "fd/2"`
I need something that also works on windows - what would `myfile = fd/2` be there please? 
I seem to have figured out that I can use `exist` to check for a file's existence.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
D:\TEMP>type error.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

D:\TEMP>dir nonexistingfile.txt 2>error.txt
 Volume in drive D is HDD
 Volume Serial Number is D46B-804B

 Directory of D:\TEMP


D:\TEMP>type error.txt
File Not Found

D:\TEMP>
```

see [microsoft-docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout)

EDIT: according to the docs, that @Raymond linked, i've seen that ist is possible to redirect error under Windows.

```
D:\TEMP>del error

D:\TEMP>echo hallo | gawk "{ print \"Serious error detected!\" > \"/dev/stderr\"; print $0 }" 2>error
hallo

D:\TEMP>type error
Serious error detected!
```

or, more conditional:

```
D:\TEMP>del error

D:\TEMP>gawk "BEGIN{ for (i=1; i<=4; i++) { if (i%2==0) { myfile=\"/dev/stderr\" } else { myfile=\"/dev/stdout\" }; print i >myfile }}" 2>error
1
3

D:\TEMP>type error
2
4

D:\TEMP>
```

Comment: OK, i do think you cannot refer to `fd/2` from within `gawk`. It is possible to redirect the output of a statement to stderr, (see link)

Comment: In the OP, they want to redirect to stderr conditionally.

Comment: [According to the gawk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Special-FD.html): "These special file names work for all operating systems that gawk has been ported to, not just those that are POSIX-compliant: ... /dev/stderr = The standard error output (file descriptor 2)."

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work with using /dev/stderr on Windows so using that :).